# Can I prevent Mongodb $set from the client side with Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need help not allowing a visitor to increase their score in the browser console of a meteor app.

Currently a "hacker" can increase his game score by typing this in the console:

Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.userId()}, {$set:{"profile.score":1000000}})

Comment: Please read the documentation of meteor before asking questions. what you are looking for are the allow/deny rules (http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-allow).

Answer (score 1):

@Vasil Nedyalkov's answer could be considered right, but I would do this instead:

```
Meteor.users.deny({
  insert() { return true; },
  update() { return true; },
  remove() { return true; },
});
```

As well as removing `insecure` and `autopublish` like he said.

This is a good explanation:
https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the 'insecure' and the 'autopublish' package.  Please see https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods

Answer (score 0):

remove the 'insecure' and the 'autopublish' package as Khai said.
and add

```
Meteor.users.allow({
   update:function(){
      return false;
   }
})
```

on server side